# Как задать ширину элементов BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, меню

Здравствуйте!
Скажите пожалуйста, можно ли задавать собственную ширину для элементов BottomNavigationView (встроенный виджет от Android)?
В частности у меня есть 4 элемента меню, я хочу задать им соотношение по ширине 4:4:3:1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/favorites"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_favorites"
        android:title="Избранное"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_keyboard"
        android:title="Позвонить" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/contacts"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_contacts"
        android:title="Контакты" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_settings"
        android:title="" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Скорее всего это невозможно без диких, аццких хаков. В этом случае проще использовать разметку из обычный вьюх + своя анимация. Согласно гайдам гугла этот виджет сам должен определять размеры своих ячеек

Comment: Спасибо!
Жалко, что нельзя...